# How to IndexKeysDefinitionBuilder change to IndexKeysDefinition (MongoDB in C#)

Tags: c#, mongodb

I have the following code where I am stuck a little bit:

```
var indexBuilder = Builders<T>.IndexKeys;

if (setting.IsDescending)
        indexBuilder.Descending(setting.Column);
else
        indexBuilder.Ascending(setting.Column);

var indexOptions = new CreateIndexOptions();
if (setting.IsUnique)
        indexOptions.Unique = true;

var model = new CreateIndexModel<T>(indexBuilder, indexOptions);
```

I got the following error:

> Argument 1: cannot convert from 'MongoDB.Driver.IndexKeysDefinitionBuilder' to 'MongoDB.Driver.IndexKeysDefinition'

I am not sure why as I have done the same as it is in official [documentation](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.17/reference/driver/definitions/#index-keys-definition-builder).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a variable with `IndexKeysDefinition<T>` and pass it to the `CreateIndexModel` as below:

```cs
IndexKeysDefinition<T> index;
var indexBuilder = Builders<T>.IndexKeys;

if (setting.IsDescending)
    index = indexBuilder.Descending(setting.Column);
else
    index = indexBuilder.Ascending(setting.Column);

var indexOptions = new CreateIndexOptions();
if (setting.IsUnique)
    indexOptions.Unique = true;

var model = new CreateIndexModel<T>(index, indexOptions);
```

> Demo

[image]